# Failed to Parse BICEP File

Tags: azure-bicep

I am trying to deploy a sample Azure BICEP file - just a simple vnet / subnets. When I attempt the deployment using Az CLI, I get the following error:

> **Failed to parse './baseinfra.bicep', please check whether it is a valid JSON format**

```
    //deploy virtual network & subnets
param vnetName string
param snetName string
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param vnetAddressPrefixes string
param snet1Prefix string
param snet2Prefix string
param resourceTags object

resource vnet1 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2020-07-01' = {
  name: '${vnetName}-01'
  location: location
  tags: resourceTags
  properties: {
    addressSpace: {
      addressPrefixes: [
        vnetAddressPrefixes
      ]
    }
    subnets:[
      {
        name: '${snetName}-01'
        properties:{
          addressPrefix: snet1Prefix
        }
      }
      {
        name: '${snetName}-02'
        properties:{
          addressPrefix: snet2Prefix
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Called using Module

```
module vnet './vnet.bicep' = {
  name: 'vnetDeploy'
  params: {
    vnetName: 'azmech-eastus2-vnet'
    snetName: 'azmech-eastus2-snet'
    vnetAddressPrefixes: '10.0.0.0/26'
    snet1Prefix: '10.0.0.0/28'
    snet2Prefix: '10.0.0.16/28'
    resourceTags: {
      Environment: 'Dev'
      Project: 'Bicep Tutorial'
    }
  }
}
```

Any input appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

wrong version of Azure CLI installed. Must be 2.20.0 or greater. I had an older one so it did not recognize the new BICEP file.

Answer (score 2):

The correct cmd should be `az upgrade`
as in my case az cli was already and when upgraded its now `2.26.1`

```
azure-cli                         2.14.2
core                              2.14.2
telemetry                          1.0.6
```

Bicep version

```
Bicep CLI version 0.4.412 (f1169d063e)
```

Answer (score 1):

To upgrade Bicep run the cli command

```
$ az bicep upgrade
```